# How to convert WORD + "/" + WORD + "/" + WORD to std::string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to convert in this format:

```
std::string = WORD + "/" + WORD + "/" + WORD;
```

But, the problem when I've tried this way, I've get a weird value, I can't find how to deal this?

```
std::string = (char)WORD + "/" + (char)WORD + "/" + (char)WORD;
```

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: `WORD` is 16 bit..  `(char)` is probably for 8 bit. try `static_cast<WORD>(WORD_VALUE)`

Comment: Use an stringstream. You cannot append integers directly (and yes, WORD is, for example, a widely used #define in the WINAPI)

Comment: "I've get a weird value" is not a problem description that is meaningful. If you're having a problem and want us to help you solve it, be specific and explain that problem clearly.

Comment: You never declared a variable of type string which might be the issue.

Comment: `std::string = WORD ...` isn't a valid statement! Did you mean `std::string myStringVar = WORD ...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your first operand as an `std::string`, so it can use the `operator+()` member function declared in [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/):

```
std::string word = std::string() + WORD + "/" + WORD + "/" + WORD;
```

If `WORD` is not a `char*`, a `std::string` or a `char`, you should use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/?kw=ostringstream), which handles more types (see [`operator<<()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)) :

```
#include <sstream>
// ...
std::ostringstream stream;
std::string word;

stream << WORD << '/' << WORD << '/' << WORD;
word = stream.str();
```

Comment: How to display it into `TEXT()` please? maybe `TEXT("%s")`? (std::string word)

Comment: Well you just have to add `TEXT('` before, and `')` after. This way : `stream << "TEXT('" << WORD << '/' << WORD << '/' << WORD << "')";`